# Set Gameobject in Canvas to Network Player Prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My project uses the network manager to load a player prefab. I have a gameobject (Bunch of texts and 1 panel) as a child of the Canvas. The canvas is not a prefab nor a child of the player prefab.

I have a script under the player prefab trying to get the activeself of the gameobject but I am not able to set the gameobject under the player prefab (unless the gameobject is a prefab) or use the code "finditwithatag".

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Return) && PlayerStatMenuTimer>=1 && GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PlayerStatsMenu").activeSelf==false)
{
    //code here
}
```

The code above (is under the player prefab script function "Update") is not able to find my gameobject called "PlayerStatsMenu". it keeps giving me an error saying:

***" NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object PlayerController.Update () (at Assets/Evermore/PlayerController.cs:104)"***

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GameObject.FindWithTag` and `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` find GameObjects that have a certain **tag**. Tag is a property that is separate from the GameObject's name. If you set the tag property of the GameObject to the correct value (through the Editor for example), then you should be able to find it.

Also: Both these methods only find GameObjects that are active. You can not find inactive GameObjects by tag, so the condition `GameObject.FindWithTag("PlayerStatsMenu").activeSelf == false` can never be true by definition.

Maybe the best approach would be to keep the tagged object active all the time, and let it have a child that you can then activate and deactivate as you please.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag` instead of `GameObject.Find`.

Edit: Also, it is `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag`. This returns an empty array when no objection are found. You would not be able to access the array without an indexer, so I'm sure you should double check the spelling of the function either in your code or in your question.

Comment: I just tried replacing it with "Find" but it still gave me the same error message

Comment: Then there is something else wrong with the setup. Either your object is not tagged with "PlayerStatsMenu" when using `GameObject.FidnGameObjectWithTag`, or your object is not named "PlayerStatsMenu" when using `GameObject.Find`

Comment: I have triple checked and the gameobject are indeed tagged and named properly. I even copied the name and tag and pasted into my code instead of typing it just to be sure and I still get the same error :(   not sure if it's because the player is a prefab or not

Comment: One thing to note, it's `FindGameObjectsWithTag`: note the `s`. This returns an array of 0 elements if it does not find them. You will need to access the array normally. There is also `FindWithTag` that will return a single element.